# Construct URL from Postman Basic Authentication

Tags: rest, curl, postman, basic-authentication

Hi I'm trying to construct a URL for the following Postman Basic Authentication. The value in Username is the API Token or API key.

[image]

I've tried:

```
https://company.clearbit.com/v1/domains/find?name=Jackson marketing&Username=myAPIYeywhichisblackedoutinimage
```

In postmane it works, but with the URL I get:

```
{
  "error": {
    "type": "auth_required",
    "message": "Authentication is required for this action. Sign up at https://clearbit.com"
  }
}
```

How do I construct a URL suitable to but and paste into a browser?

John

Answer (score 1):

Basic authentication requires you to set the [Authorization header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) in the HTTP request, so you won't be able to just paste a URL into the browser, you'll need to construct the request with the header set (like you are in Postman).